# Simulate Markov Chain using R

Tags: r, distribution, montecarlo, markov-chains

Simulate Markov Chain with a transition matrix

```
#transition matrix
 P = matrix(c(.4, .3, .5, 0, .5, 0, 0, .3, .4), nrow = 3, ncol = 5,
               byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clear what you are exactly looking for. If you are trying to obtain the transition matrix after `10` and `100` times, you can keep track of the evolution progress via `Reduce`, where option `accumulate` should be set to `TRUE`

```
P10 <- Reduce(`%*%`,replicate(10,P,simplify = FALSE),accumulate = TRUE)
P100 <- Reduce(`%*%`,replicate(100,P,simplify = FALSE),accumulate = TRUE)
```